# How to return a promise from an angular directive to the controller?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-promise, 2-way-object-databinding

So I have a controller rendering a page, and have directive inside controller's template.
I  pass controller's scope variables to directive in order to change them inside directive with 2-way binding.
Directive creates a promise inside it's link() function and I want to be able to put handler on this promise in my controller, but not inside directive.

So what is the way to bind promise in directive to controller's scope variable?